# Outputting SQL result as operable PHP code

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I think that I am experiencing a lack of vocabulary. As my question deals with PHP and SQl the first five million pages on Google return how to get the two to talk.

What I am hoping to find or get the vocabulary to find is how I can use the result from a SQL query (run by a PHP code and formatted as I need it) to be run as PHP code.

Essentially what I want is below:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {    
        echo $result[$i]['PHP'];                
    }
```

where each SQL query row is a snippet of PHP code and the echo'ed code is operable PHP not printed to screen as this would do.

I feel it is as simple as changing echo to a different command, but not being able to ask this question in a way that Google gives me any starting point I'm at a loss.

Any help you could offer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`eval`](https://www.php.net/eval), but be very cautious in it's use, as it can open rather large security holes with improperly validated input.

Beyond that, consider the design complexity introduced by using dynamic programming - it may be the correct answer for your situation, but in most cases it is not needed and just complicates things unnecessarily.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I take your point on the possibility of eval being used for evil. I can mitigate the ability for SQL or even PHP injection as this is not for the big bad internet, just local. But I might experiment on what I can get away with injection wise, just to see. ;)